# How to search starting place to delivery place using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a web page using php, in this page I have to search starting place to delivery place details using php is this possible?

My code is the following:

**index.php**

```
<form id="contactForm" action="index.php" novalidate>
   <label>Starting Place</label>
   <input type="text" name="starting_place" placeholder="Enter Starting Place">
   <label>Starting Place</label>
   <input type="text" name="delivery_place" placeholder="Enter Starting Place">
   <input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
</form>
<?php
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from place where "); // this is my question

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        echo $row['starting_place'];
        echo $row['delivery_place'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: both input is starting place??

Comment: sorry that is delivery_place@niranjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_*` is deprecated, use mysqli_*`or`pdo` instead

Check this query:

```
$start = $_POST['starting_place'];
$end = $_POST['delivery_place'];
$sql = mysql_query("select * from place where starting_place = $start and ending_place = $end ");
```

Comment: yes it's working but i need to filter staring place to delivery place

Comment: and how to echo this function

Comment: did u changed the spelling mistake??

Comment: Glad I could help u:)

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is not good

```
$sql =mysql_query("select * from place where ");
```

maybe you ment something like this

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$sql =mysql_query("select * from `place` where `starting_place` = '$search' ");
```

of full php code

```
include 'db.php';
   if(isset($_POST['search']))
   {
       $search = $_POST['search'];
       $sql =mysql_query("select * from `place` where `starting_place` = '$search' ");
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
       {
           echo $row['starting_place'];
           echo $row['delivery_place'];
       }
   }
```

Comment: i need to filter starting_place to delivery_place@Standej

Comment: how do you mean to filter delivery_place to starting_place? @GokulGiri

Comment: Maybe you mean this:$sql =mysql_query("select * from `place` where `delivery_place` = '$search' ");

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. I will assume you only have one input field:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="index.php" novalidate>
    <label>Starting Place</label>
    <input type="text" name="starting_place" placeholder="Enter Starting Place">
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
</form>
```

Then, your php code should look like this:

```
$starting_place = $_POST['starting_place']; //name of your input box

if (isset($starting_place)) {
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from place where place='" . $starting_place . "'"); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo $row['starting_place'];
        echo $row['delivery_place'];
    }
}
```